# Why does Maven "includes" in parent excluded dependencies

Tags: maven

Why does Maven not inherit excluded dependencies?

For Example, if I use a parent POM and a dependency:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And `spring-boot-starter-parent` excludes for `activemq-spring` commons-logging:commons-logging`.

The dependency tree looks like this:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.3.0:tree (default-cli) @ MavenTest ---
[INFO] org.example:MavenTest:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.apache.activemq:activemq-spring:jar:5.16.5:compile
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:jar:4.21:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:jar:5.16.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:jar:5.16.5:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.fusesource.hawtbuf:hawtbuf:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-openwire-legacy:jar:5.16.5:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.13.4.2:compile
[INFO]    |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.4:compile
[INFO]    |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-pool:jar:5.16.5:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.activemq:activemq-jms-pool:jar:5.16.5:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO]    \- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.11.1:compile
```

If I now add a `<dependencyManagement>` and exclude another dependency:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
          <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
          <version>${activemq.version}</version>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
              <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

The dependency tree contains in parent excluded `commons-logging:commons-logging` and does not contain `org.slf4j:slf4j-api`.

```
[INFO] \- org.apache.activemq:activemq-spring:jar:5.16.5:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:jar:4.21:compile
[INFO]    |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:jar:5.16.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:jar:5.16.5:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.fusesource.hawtbuf:hawtbuf:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-openwire-legacy:jar:5.16.5:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.13.4.2:compile
[INFO]    |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.4:compile
[INFO]    |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-pool:jar:5.16.5:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.activemq:activemq-jms-pool:jar:5.16.5:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO]    \- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.11.1:compile
```

I was expecting that both exclusions, `commons-logging:commons-logging` and `org.slf4j:slf4j-api` will be excluded. But this is not the case.

Why does Maven not inherit parent exclusion?

Comment: maybe you can add `<version>` also to dependency definition.

Comment: `<version>` is provided in `<dependencyManagement>` in parent POM or in current POM when "overridden". Even when I add a `<version>` the problem stays.